# How can I disconnect from openvpn in windows via command line?

Tags: openvpn

I know how to connect to an openvpn via a command line in Windows XP.  What I can't figure out is how to end the connection.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

press F4 (it's listed in the title bar of the command window).

Comment: -1 they're looking for command line, not keyboard shortcuts

Comment: That's the correct answer: When you're starting `openvpn.exe` on command line, the only way to disconnect is to hit F4. `CTRL-C` is ineffective.

Answer (score 4):

Its looks like openvpn doesnot have disconnect option.
But you can use taskkill command to disconnect the vpn connection.
I have tested myself. It is properly disconnecting instead of abruptly killing openvpn.

**`taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe`**

Answer (score 4):

The above answers didn't work for me. The question is about Windows XP, but I thought I would answer for Windows 10 anyway.

You can now run the GUI program with a large number of options. To disconnect a specific client execute the following (this worked in October 2019 with OpenVPN version 11.10 64bit)

```
"c:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --command disconnect <client-name>
```

Or disconnect all connections, regardless of name

```
"c:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --command disconnect_all
```

Many other options are also available

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the service with:

```
net stop openvpnservice
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this works for XP or when it was introduced, but you can now use this to disconnect

```
"%ProgramFiles\OpenVPN Technologies\OpenVPN Client\core\ovpncli.exe" disconnect
```

on 64bit

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)\OpenVPN Technologies\OpenVPN Client\core\ovpncli.exe" disconnect
```

I know old post, but this is the first result google gave when I was looking how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

they often have the command

`vpnc-disconnect`

Answer (score -1):

Refer below link, that might help you...

http://pwnt.be/2009/08/01/automating-openvpn-connection-on-windows-xp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.